# Curly double quotes rendering as large acute accents

Tags: punctuation

I was trying to enclose a backslash and a visible space symbol inside double quotes with conventional ``` `` '' ``` as in ``` (i.e. ``\backslash\textvisiblespace '') ```. But the closing quotes came as large front slanting accents (acute accents - image), slightly bigger than:`´´`. Also in the following text the line breaks are somehow prevented (image).

Source code is this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
 some text (i.e. ``'\backslash\textvisiblespace '') some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\end{document}
```

I tried using different codes but I still got the acute accents. Is there a solution to this?
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Probably some packages you load (`babel`?) change the behaviour of some characters. You could use `\rq\rq` as a substitute (it's a TeX primitive), but to understand the source of your problem a MWE is in order I think

Comment: @Moriambar, see the edit. No packages or fancy stuff. Just simple code.

Comment: gotcha, answering

Comment: if you get a tex error don't even look at the pdf output except for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I know what's going on. You used the `backslash` command, which has to be used in math mode.

**Explanation**

Your code causes two errors, which you should carefully examine:

> ```
> ./Yourfilename.tex:4: Missing $ inserted.
>  <inserted text> 
>                 $
>  l.4  some text (i.e. ``\backslash
>                              \textvisiblespace '') some text some text s...
> ```

TeX is telling you that it is not able to typeset `\backslash` in text mode, and tells you it is going to insert a `$` to switch to math mode in order to typeset the character. This basically causes the second error (in which TeX sees that the document ends without closing the math mode, and it remedies to that inserting the closing `$`. This basically causes `''` to be interpreted as two primes (like in `$f'$`).

**SOLUTION**

Use `textbackslash`, which typeset the `\` in text mode.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
 some text (i.e. ``\textbackslash\textvisiblespace '') some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text 

\end{document}
```

[image]